# Genetics... Translocation

Tags: molecular-genetics, pathology, human-genetics, chromosome, medicine

Can a Translocation of chromosomal parts occur between an autosome and an allosome?
If it occurs in between allosomes,what could be the effect of Robertsonian Translocation between an X and a Y chromosome considering the fact that the small product of a Robertsonian Translocation is mostly lost!??!

Answer (score 1):

> Can a Translocation of chromosomal parts occur between an autosome and an allosome?

In short, yes. A quick scan of a few abstracts gives both [clinical](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/m/pubmed/11590891/) and [model organism](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/m/pubmed/8243168/) examples.

> [I]f it occurs in between allosomes,what could be the effect of Robertsonian Translocation between an X and a Y...

It seems Robertsonian translocations are not ubiquitous amongst the chromosomes and [only involve 13, 14, 15, 21 and 22](http://www.genetics.edu.au/genetics/Publications%20and%20Resources/Genetics-Fact-Sheets/Changes-to-Chromosome-Structure-Translocations-FS7).

HTH.